# webhost webfaction: site navigation

Tags: python, cherrypy, webfaction

I'm new to webfaction and I want to run a cherrypy app I've developed. It runs fine on my localhost and I'm trying to put it on a website so it seems like all I need to do is copy and paste the code to the site.py file that was created when I created a cherrypy app at webfaction.

This is a really beginner question but how do I navigate to this site.py file to edit it? I'm having trouble navigating there site. Anyone here also use webfaction?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SSH or FTP, then from go to  `webapps/NAME_OF_YOUR_APP/`

This is the documentation on [how to access your data on webfaction](http://docs.webfaction.com/user-guide/access.html).